# Query in Elementor Pro to display posts by Custom Taxonomy

Tags: wordpress, elementor, custom-taxonomy

My issue is related to WordPress / Elementor, but I need help in fixing (modifying) a query. Not sure if this is the right place to post this.

For an Elemnetor Pro based web project, I have set up a custom template that displays some Custom fields coming from the ACF and Custom Post Type UI. The page also includes a Post Widget which is supposed to display the latest posts that are tagged with a Custom Taxonomy that was created in CPT and successfully integrated through ACF and tagged for each Custom Post.

I found a solution that almost does what I aim to achieve by adding a query by creating a snippet and applying a query ID to the Widget in Elementor settings.

The issue is that it displays the related post by WordPress tags smoothly, but I need it to display by Custom Taxonomy.

Following is the query that was taken from https://www.metronovacreative.com/website-design/match-current-pages-terms-elementor-custom-queries/

This works great for the WP tags. Can someone help me edit this query to get the custom taxonomy instead of the tags?

Not a developer, so absolutely have no idea what should be done. Your help is highly appreciated.

```
add_action( 'elementor/query/limitpost', function( $query ) {
    $tag_objects = get_the_tags();
foreach( $tag_objects as $temp_tag) {
$tag_slugs\[\] = $temp_tag-\>slug;
}

    $query->set( 'tag_slug__in', $tag_slugs );
    $query->set( 'post_type', 'post' );
    $query->set( 'post_status', 'publish');
    $query->set( 'order', 'DESC');
    $query->set( 'orderby', 'date' );

} );
```